# Do inputs have a minimum value in order to be "standard" transactions?

Tags: bitcoin-core, dust, non-standard-transaction

I am aware that a transaction which creates an output below dust value is considered "non-standard" and not relayed by default nodes.

Does a similar rule apply for *spending* a utxo?

For example, imagine there already exists a mined utxo with an output value of 1 (below dust). I attempt to spend this utxo (appending another input to help pay the mining fee). Will my new transaction also be considered non-standard due to the low-valued input or is it considered standard?

Answer (score 1):

No, the dust rule only applies to transaction outputs, and it wouldn't make sense otherwise. The policy exists to prevent the creation of outputs that would likely live forever because they are not economical to spend, but if they end up being created and someone wants to spend them anyway, we don't want to stop them.

You can find the source code for this policy rule [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/8105bce5b384c72cf08b25b7c5343622754e7337/src/policy/policy.cpp#L144).